# Text resize in element based on width, for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize

https://jsfiddle.net/bx060jsd/10/

I've created JavaScript/jQuery, below:

```
        curWidth = document.getElementById('tagPhrase').offsetHeight;
    for (i = 30; curWidth > 100; i--) {
        $('#tagPhrase').css("font-size", i);
    }
```

Which is designed to lower the font size within `#tagPhrase` while the offsetHeight of `#tagPhrase` is greater than 100. It doesn't seem to be working however. What am I missing?

Comment: Please explain this for (i = 30; curWidth > 100; i--) !!!

Comment: What I want is For i = 30, and current offsetWidth is greater than 100, subtract from i (font size) until offsetWidth is no longer greater than 100.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**Html:**

```
<p id="tagPhrase" style="font-size:50px">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. 
</p>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var element = document.getElementById('tagPhrase'), 
    curWidth = element.offsetWidth,
  currentFontSize = parseInt(element.style.fontSize);

while(curWidth > 100 && currentFontSize > 2) {
    currentFontSize--;
  element.style.fontSize = currentFontSize+"px";
  curWidth = element.offsetWidth;
}
```

**Demo:**

https://jsfiddle.net/vz2j8baj/

Comment: This does work but I want the font just to get small enough to fit within the 100px area, not to font size 2. What changes can I make to do that?

Comment: By fit, you mean one line ?! because it can always fit !

Comment: Yes one-line. How do I do that?

Comment: The container has a fixed width (100px) with dynamic text ! and you want that the text shows up on one line ?!